# macOS 11.0.1 - Flutter doctor gives cocopods error

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, macos-big-sur

I was stuck with cocoapods problem while trying to install Flutter on my computer. Although I was constantly installing it, it was not seen by the flutter doctor. How can I solve this problem?

```
    blackx@Black-Air ~ % sudo flutter doctor
Password:
   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
  /

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale tr-TR)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Did you install it with brew?

Comment: I've tried so many things. Including installing the brewle.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

I just looked up my .bash_history and tried to remember, so I don't know if all below is relevant or in the right order or complete. So here are more or less random commands which might help you.

In the flutter/ios folder

`rm Podfile.lock`

`pod repo update`

Elsewhere

`sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew`

`sudo brew cleanup -d -v`

`gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2`

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

`rvm install ruby`

`xcode-select --install`

`sudo brew tap --repair`

`brew install cocoapods`

`brew link cocoapods`

`git -C /user/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`

If you do find out how to actually do it, please remember the order of your commands so you can post them here too :)

Comment: I've tried all the commands. Everything went well, but the last time I ran the flutter doctor, it still couldn't confirm that the cocoapods were loaded ...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `sudo chmod -R a+w /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0` 
Step 2: `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.2`
Step 3: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

This problem most probably occur because your flutter service needs super user privileges. You can fix this using this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/yourUser/flutter/
```

Change yourUser with your Macos username and run flutter doctor without sudo.